# Is there a way to make @sys-time more reliable?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text, watson-assistant

I am having issues getting @sys-time to work as expected.  Even while tweaking settings, IBM watson does not recognize simple variations on time that would be expected when using speech-to-text.

Examples I would expect to work from the docs here:https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-system-entities#system-entities-sys-date-time

Examples that I have used as input that don't register any confidence as the @sys-time entity (even with/without the new irrelevance and intent detection):

- 10
- 1030
- at 1030 AM
- 1
- two

Examples that do actually work:

- Two hours from now
- at 10
- 2 a clock

If I create a generic number entity, where it matches digits, then the confidence in that does show up, but obviously that's not the goal (or intended use of sys-time).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is that question tagged as "speech-to-text"? Any problems with that? What is the full input, what are your intents and entities and what is detected? How do you access the system entity data?

Comment: It's tagged speech to text because the sorts of times picked up by speech to test when you say for example "ten thirty" aren't picked up as sys-time.  We are accessing the json object as it comes back from and hits the voice gateway to look at the entities picked up.  Zero confidence for these numbers as a sys-time, if i put in a generic number entity, it will pick up confidence as a regular number.  I will edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Have you tried creating your own entity and training it to be detected for those variations? No need to use any system entities.

Comment: I forgot to ask: Is sys-time enabled in your dialog skill?

Comment: It wouldn't work the same as the sys-time entity, because of how sys-time will resolve to a specific date when you say "two hours from now" for example.  I don't think that could be replicated without a bunch of JS.  Yes, sys-time is enabled as well as sys-date.  I will update my question to reflect the input in which it works